# can't generate sequence diagram from running code - Enterprise Architect

Tags: jvm, java, enterprise-architect

I'd like to generate sequence diagrams with EA. I set up a build script, the debug section looks like this:

> jre=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20,-Djava.class.path=C:\path\to\my\app

When I try to debug it (which is needed for the diagram generation), I get the following message:

> Failed to load C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll, dll or dependent dll is missing

The file jvm.dll is indeed located at the path it tries to load it from. What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi Tamás, Have you tried to put quotes surround your path ?
I think that it's needed because the existence the the space.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this. I having the same problem.

Comment: No, unfortunately. It seems like it's a very buggy area in this otherwise decent software.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:
Enterprise Architect(EA) is having some struggles using the "Program Files" directories.

Reason Why(Partial):
I copied the jvm.dll out of its %java_home%\jre\bin\client directory and put it in c:\Temp to test if EA could now "see" the file.
Sure enough, when I pointed EA to the new location it found it just fine. The test still wouldn't run, but at least the file could be "seen" by EA.

Resolution:
Re-install the JDK to a non-"Program Files" and non-"Program Files(x86)" directory, then re-point all of the pertinent System Environment Variables (e.g. JAVA_HOME, PATH) and Enterprise Architect Commands to the newly installed JDK location.

Answer (score 0):

There is always FilePathName 8.3 equivalent in Windows.

Instead of `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05`

You can write (or similar): `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_05`

Try in Dos prompt: `dir C:\PROGRA~1`